# Why Membership.GetUser() tries to create table Applications?

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

As I can see in VS2012 debugger, method Membership.GetUser() first of all tries to create table 'Applications' (with CREATE TABLE NonQuery), gets exception that table is already exists and then returns correct MembershipUser for me. I cann’t understand, why it attempts to create existing table? EVERY call to GetUser or GetAllUsers results in attempt to create existing table... It eats performance and I want to get rid of this.

I use .NET Framework 4.5, MVC4, new db scheme for users and roles (w/o aspnet_ prefix).

Thank you for help!

Comment: I have this issue too, but only when I install Mini-Profiler. Otherwise I don't get this error!

Answer (score 1):

It should only be doing this once per app domain when its trying to initialize the databases.  Are you getting these exceptions even when not reseting the server on each page request?

Comment: I get it every call of GetUser or GetAllUsers even in the same method! If I call it 10 times, I have 10 exceptions... It loads server's CPU by 100%. I have never seen this before (I created more then 100 projects on ASP.NET). Now I wrote my own membership provider. It works very fast and w/o errors. But that problem is not solved by me. I spent about 8 hours on it and understand nothing. Craziness.